# Logging Count of Those Who Read Whole Post (ie reach the bottom)

Tags: logging

I want to log when a visitor to a post reads to the bottom. I figure the code would work similar to an infinite scroll (measuring window and the location of an element in that window) but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Places to start:

1. [Detecting Bottom of the page](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jquery%20detect%20scrolling%20to%20bottom%20of%20page)
2. Once you have detected you're at the bottom, you'll need to make an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request using [WP AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) ([tutorial](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=wp%20ajax%20tutorial)) to save that data.

You'll probably want to store "read_whole_post" as a postmeta value. Something along the lines of this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_read_whole_post', 'se200479_read_whole_post' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_read_whole_post', 'se200479_read_whole_post' );

function se200479_read_whole_post() {
    // Passed through jQueryAjax in the settings.data argument
    $post_id = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'post_id' );

    // Will return the existing count - ie 0
    $current_count = absint(get_post_meta( $post_id, 'read_whole_post', true ));

    // increment your count
    $current_count++;

    // Update the database value
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'read_whole_post', $current_count );

    // Terminate the AJAX request
    wp_send_json_success();
}
```

You'll also want to consider storing something on the page in your JS, like `updated = true` to make sure you don't increase your count value multiple times if someone scrolls up and down the page a bunch!